# preg_match_all exclude PHP predefined methods

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I'm use PHP to load controller names into a table and the names of its public methods in to another table. I want to exclude any PHP magic methods as they're not really publicly available.

The contents of the file that's being read are ...

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->has_access() ;
  }
}
```

I'm using the following regex to exclude methods that start with __ as that usually denotes a magic method

```
preg_match_all('/^\s*public\s+function\s+(?<!__)(\w.*)\b/Uim', file_get_contents('Dashboard.php', $public_methods, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) ;
```

What I'm expecting is that all text from the beginning of the line up to and including the last space character after the text "function" will be discarded, the text after the last space character until the end of the following word (the name of the method) will be included UNLESS the method name starts with __ in which case there will be no match.

What I'm getting though is ..

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [0] =>  function __construct
          [1] =>  function index
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [0] => __construct
          [1] => index
      )
)
```

What I don't want are the elements with `__construct` in them.

I've tried

- altering the initial \w to \b, that was a disaster, there were no method names found
- altering the position of the \w to outside the (.*) which didn't work well
- combinations of `(?<!__)` and `(?<!_)`

I'm admitting defeat and asking for help, what do I need to do to the regex to exclude methods that start with __ ?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Brief

You should not use regex to parse things that are not a regular language, but, in any case, this is what you're looking for...

Your pattern isn't working because you use `(?<!__)`, which is a negative lookbehind. You need to use a lookahead because a `\s+(?<!__)` will always return true (`\s+` cannot contain `__` and since it's a `lookbehind` it's looking behind the current location). A `lookahead` will look ahead (hence the name). Changing `(?<!__)` to `(?!__)` will work, but I've added a nice `\K` reset token to your pattern. See **Code** section.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/w4Nivx/1)

```
^\s*public\s+function\s+(?!__)\K\w+\b
```

---

### Explanation

I'll only explain what I changed:

- `(?!__)` Ensure what follows doesn't match `__` literally. You can also substitute this for `(?!_{2})` for a *very slight* performance increase.
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.